# CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long

Tags: ant, findbugs

I'm trying to *call* **Findbugs** via **Ant**, but receiving this error:

```
Cannot run program "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin\javaw.exe" (in 
directory "H:\Users\MyName\workspace\MyProject"): 
CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long
```

How can I fix this? o.O

Comment: How are you calling findbug? directly running findbug or using findbug task?

Comment: using findbug task. the problem persist...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long when running main() method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10519558/608639), [Createprocess error=206; the filename or extension is too long](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26730838/608639) and friends.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem.
I used

```
<fileset dir="${basedir}/build">
  <include name="**/*.class"/>
</fileset>
```

inside findbugs target and it seems that there is too much .class files to be passed to findbug (?via command line?) because when I used

```
<fileset dir="${basedir}/build/com/domain/package">
  <include name="**/*.class"/>
</fileset>
```

that had low number of classes, the error was gone.

So, I solved the problem by making one jar file and feeding it to findbugs target with

```
<findbugs home="${findbugs.home}">
  ...
  <class location="${basedir}/targets/classes-to-analyze.jar"/>
</findbugs>
```

Comment: I had the same problem but with `<jacoco:coverage>` and `<junit>`. There was a `<classpath>` with a `<dirset>` with many, many classes. I made a JAR with `<jar destfile="${test.dist}/test-classes.jar"...` and changed the `<classpath>` to `<pathelement location="${test.dist}/test-classes.jar"/>`. Then it worked!

Answer (score 1):

I think one of the effective file paths are really long when java tries to compile clases.

One worth try is to put codebase in a directory such as C:\MyProject  instead of something like C:\Users\MyName\workspace\MyProject

Answer (score 1):

To solve this issue you need to generate a manifestclasspath and a pathing jar.

First Generate your classpath.

```
<path id="javac.path">
    <fileset dir="lib/" includes="**/*.jar"/>
</path>
```

Next Generate your manifestclasspath

```
<target name="generate-manifest-classpath">
    <manifestclasspath property="manifest.classpath" jarfile="pathing.jar">
        <classpath refid="javac.path"/>
    </manifestclasspath>      
    <jar destfile="pathing.jar" basedir="${the location of your build classes}">
        <manifest>            
            <attribute name="Class-Path" value="${manifest.classpath}"/>
        </manifest>
    </jar>
    <path id="javac.classpath">
        <pathelement path="pathing.jar"/>          
    </path>
</target>
```

Next Implement your Manifestclasspath

```
<javac srcdir="${foo.dir}" destdir="${bar.dir}"
        <classpath refid="javac.classpath"/>
</javac>
```

This will solve the 206 error message if implemented correctly.

Comment: This answer was really helpful - it gave me useable Ant commands to deal with the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error on IntelliJ while starting debug mode only. To fix is I've changed:

**Run** > **Edit Configurations** > **"Configuration" tab** > **Shorten command line**

to **"JAR-manifest"**