# CreateProcess error=206 The filename or extension is too long

Tags: firebase, kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea

I'm trying to run my project in IntelliJ IDEA in debug or run mode, and it is throwing me always this:

Cannot run program "C:\corretto11\bin\java.exe" (in directory "C:\project-be"): CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long

I have both in **C root**, I tried to google it and search in Stack Overflow, but nothing that I found was working.

EDIT:

The problem comes when I add the following dependency:

```
implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:8.1.0")
```

To be honest, no idea what could I do, if I remove the dependency it works like magic.

Comment: Your project file paths or classpath are too long so it fails to run. This is the windows's limitation. You could click the `Run | Edit Configuration` from the IDE main menu, select your configuration and enable `Shorten command line` option to shorten the command line.

Comment: @EgorKlepikov I tried using **JAR manifest** and **@argfile** without success

Comment: What build system do you use? (e.g. Maven, Gradle, etc...)

Comment: That works, but it's just as temporal solution, I would love to use the IntelliJ debug function to be able to debug my app.

Comment: Seems like my dependencies are too long but no idea how to resolve it

Comment: @EgorKlepikov, you must also enable dynamic classpaths in the intellij workspace.

Comment: Is this a Maven or Leiningen project?

Comment: @EgorKlepikov will this also work for a leiningen project? I'm facing this issue in my Clojure project. But none of these changes are helping.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In addition to changing the run configuration, you must **also** enable this in your workspace. It's quite silly that this is *still* required, and not *enabled by default*.

Open the file `.idea/workspace.xml` file from your project root folder, go to section

`<component name="PropertiesComponent">`

and add the following:

`<property name="dynamic.classpath" value="true" />`

Comment: It's a Kotlin specific issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-17492. An easier workaround would be to add `-Didea.dynamic.classpath=true` in Help | Edit Custom VM Options.

Comment: So I should property name & also keep the component name right?

Comment: This is most definitely _not_ a Kotlin-specific issue. IntelliJ Ultimate 2023.2 will encounter this problem with any newly-created Java Maven project using default settings.

Answer (score 8):

It works for me in intellij: Run -> Edit Configurations -> Modify options -> Shorten command line -> and select last option from Shorten command line (@argfile(Java9+))

Answer (score 4):

In addition to [Nathan answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69448835/3553118). In most recent versions, Intellij uses a Json in `<component name="PropertiesComponent">` tag.

Add the `"dynamic.classpath": "true"` property inside the `keyToString` json element.

Comment: This approach also fixes the error from the question's title happening when trying to execute a JPQL query in the JPA Console.

Comment: This resolves the same issue that commonly occurs with newly-created Java Maven projects in Intellij.

Answer (score 1):

this is how I solved this error, if you you are using windows

Follow these Steps

1. Move your .m2 folder from C:/users/user_name/.m2 to C:/.m2
2. Go to the folder maven installed  config / settings.xml
3. uncomment

   > ```
   >  <settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
   > ```

   ```
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"              
    > xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
    > http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
   ```
4. Add repository location:

> C:.m2\repository

Comment: step 4 : <localRepository>C:\.m2\repository</localRepository>

Answer (score 1):

After several days of struggling with the problem, I eventually found a solution. By enabling debug logs, I discovered that the characters in the classpath were exceeding the maximum limit of around 32k on Windows. The directory with the maximum entries in the classpath was the .m2 folder directory, which was stored in my user/{username} directory, taking up a significant chunk of characters.(use an online string analyser tool for this)

To resolve the issue, I redirected the .m2 repository to "C:" which reduced the classpath to approximately 30k characters, and the problem was resolved.

My suggestion to others facing a similar issue would be to analyze the classpath and find ways to reduce its size. Unfortunately, there is no universal solution that works for all cases.

Comment: What exactly did you type to see the debug logs and what exactly was logged out?

Answer (score 1):

In Idea `Run/Debug` configuration click `Modify Options`.

Chose `Shorten command line` and in `Shorten Command Line` drop down select `jar manifest` or `classpath file`
[Shorten command line drop down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yTYl.png)