# How to resolve this error : CreateProcess error=206 The filename or extension is too long

Tags: intellij-idea, clojure

I am running a Clojure project in IntelliJ IDEA.
And I got this error while trying to build the project(lein install)

```
Cannot run program "java" (in directory "D:\Mercury\project-avon"): CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long.
```

How do I resolve this. I have referred to this link, but it didn't resolve my issue.

[CreateProcess error=206 The filename or extension is too long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69376895/createprocess-error-206-the-filename-or-extension-is-too-long)

Comment: Is this error from running lein-the-script or some intellij task? Or in other words: does it work if you run it on commandline?

Comment: You should post in reddit.com/r/clojure instead of here.  That's a better forum for this type of thing.

P.S. Please include a copy of the project too.

Comment: Does it happen with a sample, starter Clojure project (i.e., off-the-shelf Intellij+lein) or only with a specific project? I hazily recall that this Windows error message can indicate that a Clojure-generated class name exceeds a Windows limit. IIRC long class names can result from deeply nested "anonymous" functions, especially if they have names.

Comment: If you use IDE run configuration - please check "Shorten command line" option.

Comment: @TheAlchemist I wasn't aware of  reddit.com/r/clojure. Will surely check it there once!

Comment: @y.bedrov tried that fix. Didn't help though.

Comment: Could you please attach screenshot with your run configuration?

Comment: This issue has been resolved now. I needed to uncomment a plugin dependency in project. clj. 
Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been resolved now. I needed to uncomment a plugin dependency in project. clj.