# Java 7 to Java 8 environment in App Engine - The filename or extension is too long with jsp files

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have followed the steps specified on URL https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/runtime-java8 for changing from java 7 to java 8 for standard AppEngine. I am getting following error while executing command 'mvn appengine:update'

when i have .jsp file in the webapp folder.
Even with empty jsp file i am seeing the below error.

Error log:

Beginning interaction for module lucas...
0% Created staging directory at: 'C:\Users\PRAVEE~1.KUM\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg7979878527176764844.tmp'
5% Scanning for jsp files.
8% Compiling jsp files.

java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "D:\jdk8\jre\bin\java.exe": CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long
Unable to update app: Cannot run program "D:\jdk8\jre\bin\java.exe": CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long
Please see the logs [C:\Users\PRAVEE~1.KUM\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg1814539918913564706.log] for further information.

Comment: What do your logs say about it?

Also, have you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10519558/createprocess-error-206-the-filename-or-extension-is-too-long-when-running-main) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26730838/createprocess-error-206-the-filename-or-extension-is-too-long)? They seem similar.

Comment: [Another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8850920/createprocess-error-206-the-filename-or-extension-is-too-long) that may be helpful. It's a problem with a too long classpath for Windows command to handle.