# CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long while building with Ant

Tags: java, ant, liferay

i am quite new to ant. i am trying to do Ant Build and i am getting the error " java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\jre\bin\java.exe": CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long".

i am trying to build the liferay portlet project. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Please add your Ant script.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8850920/createprocess-error-206-the-filename-or-extension-is-too-long)