# Getting IOException: Cannot run program "java": Create process error=206, The filename or extension is too long at wlcompile ant task

Tags: java, ant, ejb, weblogic12c

I'm trying to execute Ant(1.9) build from Eclipse(Kepler) for an Enterprise application project. At the wlcompile task, I'm getting the below error :

**java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "java": CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long.**

I'm also getting a warning as below, before I get the exception:

**[JAM]Warning: failed to resolve class com.bea.util.jar.JClass**

Below is the ant script:

```
<target name="build.ear">
<wlcompile srcidr="${dist} destdir"${build}/{ear}" includes="${ejb}" classpath="${lib}/${tangosolJar}">
<ejbgen source="${sourceVersion}"/>
<javac deprecation="${deprecation}"/>
</wlcompile>
</target>
```

To resolve this issue, I have tried to create an empty jar file and specify all the jars in the classpath attribute of the manifest file. I have modified wlcompile as below:
`<wlcompile srcdir="${dir}" destdir="${build}/{ear}" includes="${ejb}" classpath="manifest.classpath">`  But the classpath still has the old classpath value pointing to individual jars. How can I set the 'manifest.classpath' value in wlcompile tag?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8850920/createprocess-error-206-the-filename-or-extension-is-too-long)

Comment: I have tried to create an empty jar file and specify all the jars in the classpath attribute of the manifest file. I have modified wlcompile as below:  `code` <wlcompile srcdir="${dir}" destdir="${build}/{ear}" includes="${ejb}" classpath="manifest.classpath"> `code`                                     But the classpath still has the old classpath value pointing to individual jars. How can I set the 'manifest.classpath' value in wlcompile tag?